# In Power Query, how can I remove duplicates either side of a delimiter?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I wish to turn : into :
For example amazon:amazon becomes amazon:

This is doable by hand using the replace values function but I need a way to do it programatically.
Thanks!

Comment: is `somestring:somestring` the only thing in the cell?  Does that represent all of the variations that might exist?

Comment: No, there are plenty of variations. However there's always a space between somestring:somestring and the next string. There may also be more 2 delimiter in the field but its only the first that has this issue.

Comment: please provide several examples showing **entire** string and desired results

Comment: Did the answer by Ron Rosenfeld help you solve your problem? If so, I invite you to [mark it as accepted and/or upvote it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this **Transform** but if it doesn't work, provide detail as to the

- nature of the failure
- examples of data on which it doesn't work
- any error messages and the line which returns the error

```
   remDups = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Column1", each
        let 
            sep = ":",
            splitList = Text.Split(_, " "),
            sepString = List.FindText(splitList,sep){0},
            sepStringPosition = List.PositionOf(splitList,sepString),
            //rem if the same remove last
                splitSep = Text.Split(sepString, sep),
                replString = if splitSep{0} = splitSep{1} then splitSep{0} & sep else sepString,

            //put the string backtogether
            replList = List.ReplaceRange(splitList,sepStringPosition,1,{replString})
        in 
            Text.Combine(replList," ")    
    })
```